# Android MediaPlayer.onInfo warning (952,0)

Tags: android, android-videoview

Im trying to do an application for android 4.2.2. It just have to play some muted videos in a endless loop inside an android videoview.

It works fine but, sometimes, I get a "cannot play this video" popup, despite I see the video playing under that popup. My app is supposed to run without any input method, so... ¿Is there any chance to avoid that popup? It appears to happen randomly, sometimes after 30-40 minutes, sometimes after some hours... Its just unpredictable.

I tried to debug it and, finally adding an onInfoListener, it seems like I got the error code (952). Besides, i didnt find any help with that error... Here is the code... Any tips/help would be VERY nice, so thank you in advance...

```
...
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener PreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
     @Override
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer m) {
         try {
                if (m.isPlaying()) {
                    m.stop();
                    m.release();
                    m = new MediaPlayer();
                    m.setVolume(0f, 0f);
                }
                m.setLooping(false);
                m.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
     }
 };

video.setOnPreparedListener(PreparedListener); 
video.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {  
    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        File file = new File(myRootDirectory.getAbsolutePath()+"/logVideo.txt");
        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy//HH:mm:ss");
        String format = s.format(new Date());
        String text = format+": ("+what+","+extra+")\n";

        if(what==952){
            text = "!!!!!!!!!!\n"+text; //What is this code 952...??

        }


        FileOutputStream f = null;
        try {
               f = new FileOutputStream(file,true); //True = Append to file, false = Overwrite
               PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f);
               p.print(text);
               p.flush();
               p.close();
               f.close();       
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("Error", "******* File not found. Did you" +
                                " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest?");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        Log.d("INFO LISTENER",what+" " + extra);
        return false;
    }
});
video.setVideoPath(nextVideo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the standard "what" constants is misspelled? You might try to match against the known "what" codes (MEDIA_INFO_BAD_INTERLEAVING, etc).

Comment: Thanx for your response, however, thw "what" constants seems to be fine, and none of them are 952.

I changed the return value to "true" and seems to be working fine for now.. Can It be? Im just blindly trying different things...